# WebExtensions - get global window properties

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

So, I followed the tutorial here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension

Where you create a simple extension that modifies the DOM injecting a script.

But then I added these lines on borderify.js (a content script) :

```
console.log(window); //Prints an object that has a "$" property;
console.log(window.$); //Undefined
console.log($); //Error, "$" is undefined
```

And then I enabled it in a website I knew had JQuery in its script tags.

Which is very confusing for me, why is it that when I print the window object, it shows me an object that has the $ property, but then I try to access it, it doesn't exist?

And how do I access it?

There are some similar questions but they are all very old and it's a rapidly changing subject.

*(Please note this is unrelated to JQuery, it's just an example)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to read [Sharing objects with page scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Sharing_objects_with_page_scripts) on MDN, especially the warning!

This should work for your use-case:

```
console.log(window.wrappedJSObject.$)
```